# Copy records from a table in mysql database to a SQL-SERVER 2008 database?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, data-migration

How can I copy all the records from a table in a MySql database to another table in a SQL-SERVER 2008 database?
I have tons of records in that mysql table and I'm trying to "migrate" the data.
I tried using the "MS SQL Server Migration Assistant for Mysql", but it only migrated the structure (table names, indices, etc..).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look into SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) Packages connecting to mysql [here](http://www.ideaexcursion.com/2009/06/04/howto-connect-to-mysql-in-ssis/)

I would also see if [OPENROWSET()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx) is something that would work for you